# How long does Springer give reviewers to peer-review an original book?

Tags: peer-review, books, springer

It can take months for articles in journals. But a proportional amount of time would make it years for a book, so that cannot be it. Does anyone have a ballpark recent figure for a 90,000 word original-material manuscript?

Comment: In what field?  Many academic books are not peer reviewed at all, or if so, are only reviewed for "will it sell" instead of "is it correct, novel and significant".  Also, reviewers of books often get paid.

Comment: And, it also depends on whether it is a textbook (known material) or something more advanced.

Comment: @NateEldredge Philosophy. My question assumes peer-review is taking place. Oh, the payment could be the key to the increased speed.

Comment: @Buffy Original material.

Comment: The duration of peer review in journals is because the peer reviewers have dozens of other things to prioritize and reviewing, while important, is not something they are paid or recognized for. It doesn't mean it actually takes that long for someone to review it. They said, even for books that claim to be peer reviewed, I'm quite skeptical the level of review is ever anything like an individual article. The exception maybe would be books that are effectively compilations of a few articles.

Comment: [This blog comment](https://philosopherscocoon.typepad.com/blog/2014/06/reviewing-a-book-manuscript.html?cid=6a014e89cbe0fd970d01a73dd3b08a970d#comment-6a014e89cbe0fd970d01a73dd3b08a970d) isn't very recent, but does state three months.

Comment: @Anyon Thanks a lot, but that is over a decade old…

Comment: Do you have an example of the full text of a book being peer reviewed?  I have not heard of this,

Comment: @TerryLoring Yes, of course. For example, this series is peer-reviewed: https://www.springer.com/series/6607

Comment: I think the "Lecture Notes in X" series by Springer are usually peer-reviewed, with multiple reviewers. For example in math: https://www.springer.com/series/304

Comment: @TerryLoring Check the front matter of the book for a listing of the editorial board, editor in chief, and often the specific editor of the work. If it has these, then it's peer reviewed.